# Anyone know of an open source web spider?

Tags: web-crawler

I'm looking for a web spider that will collect all the links it sees, save those to a file, and then index those after finishing the others it has indexed. It doesn't have to have a pretty UI or really anything. As long as it can jump from website to website. It can be in any language as well, however, don't suggest Nutch.

Comment: Out of curiosity, whats wrong with Nutch?

Comment: Nutch is built for Linux, I run Windows. I also don't have a cluster of servers. Other than those things, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) will spider sites, is really configurable and is open source. It is written in C.

Not sure it will spit out a list of links, however it will save all files it runs across, which can easily then be converted to a list of links.

Comment: Is there a .exe of wget? I run Windows.

Comment: @Noah Yes, or you can definitely get it as part of cygwin (along with a ton of other *NIX type applications). http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: Alright, I installed the .exe and so now how do I use it?

Comment: @Noah You can read the manual here: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html . The short version though is that it's a console application which means you'll need to run it from `cmd.exe`. The commandline you are looking for is something along the lines of `wget -r http://example.com/`.

Answer (score 1):

I like [NCrawler](http://ncrawler.codeplex.com/), but it requires some .NET skills.

It's easy to start with and easy to extend. Have a look!